# How to disable "Merge into Current" menu item, so the Rebase Current onto Selected will be only available

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

We are only rebasing, not merging. I want to help new team members avoid pressing the wrong menu item which they should never click anyway.

I would like to know how to disable "Merge into Current" menu item, so the Rebase Current onto Selected will be only available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to configure list of actions available in Branches popup in IntelliJ IDE.

Feel free to submit a Feature request on YouTrack:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com